# Can a osgi bundle be a producer while it consumes form a another bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

Can I create a bundle to provide some service to a another bundle while that bundle also being a consumer which consumes a service from a another producer ?

Comment: yes, you can do it. you just need to add dependency of that bundle